# How to parse a string into a dataframe for readability

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have the following string that I would like to parse out for readability:

'Added term: {"guid":"4b87ce3c","qualifiedName":"Indenture Code@Enterprise","name":"Indenture Code","glossaryTermHeader":{"termGuid":"4b87ce3c","qualifiedName":"Indenture Code@Enterprise"}}'

I would like it parsed out into a dataframe that looks like:

| guid | qualifiedName | name | termGuid | qualifiedName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4b87ce3c | Indenture Code@Enterprise | Indenture Code | 4b87ce3c | Indenture Code@Enterprise |

I thought of somehow converting the string to a dictionary then pull out the key/values, but I would have keys that duplicate (ie. qualifiedName).

Any thoughts on how I can parse this out for better readability?

Comment: There is no duplicated key, because the second `qualifiedName` is under the key `glossaryTermHeader`, whereas the first `qualifiedName` is at the same level as `glossaryTermHeader`.

Comment: Oh okay!  Do you happen to know how I could parse that out as a dictionary?

Comment: It looks like a JSON object to me. You can try load the string with `json.loads(your_string)`. See documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)